# display table or html SweetAlert 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using SweetAlert2.0, This One

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

it is working fine, but now I want to display table or div or HTML element in this sweet alert.

```
var swal_html='<div class="panel"  style="background:aliceblue;font-weight:bold"><div class="panel-heading panel-info text-center btn-info"> <b>Import Status</b> </div> <div class="panel-body"><div class="text-center"><b><p style="font-weight:bold">Total number of not inserted  rows : add data</p><p style="font-weight:bold">Row numbers:Add data</p></b></div></div></div>';
swal({title:"Good Job!", content: swal_html, icon: "success"});
```

I have tried the above code just for testing, but it's not working.

I have read the documentation of this sweet alert that says, use code mentioned below.

```
swal("Write something here:", {
  content: "input",
})
.then((value) => {
  swal(`You typed: ${value}`);
});
```

but I want to display table div etc.where should I write my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem on your version. Include the latest version from CDN here:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.19.3/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
```

Also put HTML as a `html:` property not `content`, like following:

```
var swal_html = '<div class="panel" style="background:aliceblue;font-weight:bold"><div class="panel-heading panel-info text-center btn-info"> <b>Import Status</b> </div> <div class="panel-body"><div class="text-center"><b><p style="font-weight:bold">Total number of not inserted  rows : add data</p><p style="font-weight:bold">Row numbers:Add data</p></b></div></div></div>';
swal({title:"Good Job!", html: swal_html});
```

Comment: if I change my cdn, it can effect the syntax of the swal method? @Hanif

Comment: I don't think but when you use any version you should inline with corresponding guidelines, see here: https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Comment: can u plz share the documentation <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.19.3/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script> this sweet alert, so I can c the syntax of the different type of alerts. if possible? @Hanif

Comment: thanks, it is working, but I need to change the all sweet alert syntax. thanks. @Hanif

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
swal({
  html: `<table id="table" border=1>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>City</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Dakota Rice</td>
                <td>$36,738</td>
                <td>Niger</td>
                <td>Oud-Turnhout</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Minerva Hooper</td>
                <td>$23,789</td>
                <td>Curaçao</td>
                <td>Sinaai-Waas</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Sage Rodriguez</td>
                <td>$56,142</td>
                <td>Netherlands</td>
                <td>Baileux</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Philip Chaney</td>
                <td>$38,735</td>
                <td>Korea, South</td>
                <td>Overland Park</td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>`
})
```

Comment: this much only?

Comment: yes, but my sweet alert is showing directly, let me check this code. thanks